# Can one compile the Switch function?

Tags: compile, conditional, piecewise

I am aware that one can compile `Which`, e.g.:

```
ff = Compile[x, Which @@ {x < 0, 2, x >= 0, 3}
ff[1.]
```

> `3`

A drawback of `Which` is that it evaluates `x` repeatedly until one of the conditions is satisfied. This is time consuming when `x` is a complicated expression or/and when the set of conditions is large. As a far as I know, the same issue arises with `Piecewise`.

`Switch` evaluates `x` only once, but seems to be not compilable. My try was as follows:

```
gg = Compile[x, Switch[x, x < 0, 3, x >= 0, 3]]
gg[1.]
```

> CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression Null should be a machine-size real number. >>
>   CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>

Does anyone know how to compile `Switch` correctly?

Comment: Notice your first line of code isn't compiled actually because `Apply` will be compiled only if its first argument is `Times` or `Plus`.

Comment: Also, as a member for 3 years, please learn to format your code properly. And, you've totally misunderstand `Switch` in _Mathematica_, please check the document of [`Switch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Switch.html) carefully.

Comment: -1 for poor formatting; format your code, and I will remove -1.

Comment: Sorry, I earned the -1 indeed. I will invest more time in posting an answer next time. Apologies again

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> A drawback of the Which command is that it evaluates x repeatedly until one of the conditions of Which is satisfied. This is time consuming when x is a complicated expression or/and when the set of conditions is large.

This is not true in `Compile` as `x` will always be a number or an array.  Multiple uses of `x` won't slow anything down.

It isn't even true outside of `Compile` in *most* practical cases unless you defined `x` using `:=` instead of `=`.

> The command "Switch" only evaluates x once, but seems to be not compilable.

Simple forms of [`Switch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Switch.html) are compilable.  In your question, you are misusing `Switch`.  It takes patterns, not true/false conditions.  Please read the documentation.

When using it in `Compile`, only literal patterns seem to be accepted.  An exception is the last pattern, which must be `_` to handle the default case.

Example:

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Integer}},
  Switch[x,
   1, 10,
   2, 20,
   _, 0
   ]
  ]

"
        1 argument
        2 Boolean registers
        8 Integer registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        I0 = A1
        I1 = 1
        I4 = 20
        I2 = 10
        I3 = 2
        I5 = 0
        Result = I7

1   B0 = I0 == I1
2   if[ !B0] goto 5
3   I7 = I2
4   goto 11
5   B1 = I0 == I3
6   if[ !B1] goto 9
7   I6 = I4
8   goto 10
9   I6 = I5
10  I7 = I6
11  Return
"
```

If you try to use a more general pattern, such as `_Integer` or `x_ /; x > 0`, it will trigger a call to MainEvaluate (i.e. it won't be compiled) for that particular test.

**Warning:** When testing with literal patterns, it is important to be aware that `1.` and `1` are considered to be different.  We needed to explicitly specify that the input is an integer, otherwise it would be converted to a real (floating point) number, which never matches the integer `1`.  Thanks to @MichaelE2 for pointing this out!

---

In summary:

Inside `Compile`,

- use `Switch` if you need an equivalent of `switch` from C
- use `Which` if you need the equivalent of a sequence of `if ... else if ... else if ...`

Comment: Try `Compile[{x}, Switch[x, 1., 10, 2., 20, _, 0]]`.  Your input `x` is `Real` by default.  Not sure I completely understand yet...-- I guess the compiler decides that a real `x` cannot match an integer `1` or `2`, so it pre-evaluates the boolean condition to `False`.

Comment: Compare with `Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, Switch[x, 1, 10, 2, 20, _, 0]]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 You are right, not a bug.

Comment: FWIW, it's consistent with the regular *Mathematica* value of `Switch[1., 1, 10, 2, 20, _, 0]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's strange: both with version 8.0.4 and 11.0.0 I get `10` as output for `Compile[{x}, Switch[x, 1., 10, 2., 20, _, 0]][1]` and `Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, Switch[x, 1, 10, 2, 20, _, 0]][1]`. But `Switch[1., 1, 10, 2, 20, _, 0]` returns `0`. I'm on Windows 7 x64. Do you get different results?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Yes, I get the same, and it seems quite normal, no? I mean in the first case, the type of `x` is by default `_Real`, so the input `1` is first converted to the real `1.` before being passed to the compiled function.  So it  matches the case that returns `10`. In the uncompiled `Switch[..]`, the `1.` does not match `1`, since a `Real` is not an `Integer`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you, I've got the point.