# Why is this function not compilable?

Tags: functions, syntax, compile

Consider some functions

```
Condition1[func_, 1] = Boole[func > 10^-5.];
Condition1[func_, 0] = Boole[func^2 > 10^-3.];
Condition1[func_, 2] = Boole[func^3 > 10^-3.];
Condition1[func_, 3] = Boole[func > 0.001];
```

depending on a variable `func` and an integer. The following test code

```
idlist = RandomInteger[{0, 3}, 100];
compblock3 = 
 Hold@Compile[{{idlist, _Integer, 1}}, 
     Module[{count, id1}, 
      count = 0.; 
      Do[
       id1 = idlist[[i]];
       count += Condition1[10^-3, id1], {i, 1, Length[idlist], 1}];
      {count}], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True] /. 
   DownValues@Condition1 // ReleaseHold

compblock3[idlist]
```

compiles without errors. However,

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint@compblock3
```

shows problems:

```
    1 argument
    9 Integer registers
    4 Real registers
    3 Tensor registers
    Underflow checking off
    Overflow checking off
    Integer overflow checking off
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}

    T(I1)0 = A1
    I3 = 0
    I6 = 10
    I0 = 1
    I7 = 3
    R0 = 0.
    Result = T(R1)2

1   R2 = R0
2   I1 = Length[ T(I1)0]
3   I2 = I3
4   goto 12
5   I4 = Part[ T(I1)0, I2]
6   I8 = Power[ I6, I7]
7   R1 = I8
8   R3 = Reciprocal[ R1]
9   R1 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Condition1][ R3, I4]]
10  R3 = R2 + R1
11  R2 = R3
12  if[ ++ I2 <= I1] goto 5
13  T(R1)2 = {R2}
14  Return
```

Namely, `Condition1` is not compilable. I do not understand what is the reason for this.

If replacing `count += Condition1[10^-3, id1]` with e.g. `count += Condition1[10^-3, 1]`, the code compiles well.

In some realistic codes where I use `Condition1`, this leads to errors like `calls ordinary code that can be evaluated on only one thread at a time.`

Could you please tell me how to avoid the issue?

Comment: Remove final `// ReleaseHold` in `compblock3` and observe the output. Your trick with `Hold` and `/. DownValues@Condition1` is not doing anything because there are no `DownValues` for `Condition1`. You should precompile `Condition1`.

Comment: @Domen : my attempt to compile, `Condition1Comp = 
 Compile[{{func, _Real}, {i, _Integer}}, Condition1[func, i], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]`, is also not compilable. [:(].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are providing several `DownValues` for `Condition1` which you are trying to inject into your held code. But how do you expect multiple definitions to be used "simultaneously" for one call?

Instead of multiple downvalues for `Condition1`, use `Switch` which [is compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127422/can-one-compile-the-switch-function). However, note that you have to provide a "default" value with `_` or it will not compile.

```
Clear[Condition1];

Condition1[func_, id_] := 
 Switch[id, 0, Boole[func^2 > 10^-3.], 1, Boole[func > 10^-5.], 2, 
  Boole[func^3 > 10^-3.], 3, Boole[func > 0.001], _, 0]

compblock3 = Hold@Compile[...] /. DownValues@Condition1 // ReleaseHold
```

Comment: Also Switch appears in this list of compilable functions : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/86543